# npx is trying to install the package in my local machine

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

[image: screenshot the npx create-react-app my-app]

NPX is trying to install the package locally to execute it. I'm currently running the above command in WSL (Ubuntu) machine. I have the NPX installed globally as part of Node.js and it is working fine in my Windows machine but not in the WSL (Ubuntu).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Please write down the error as text, so others can easily read it, and it to be searchable.

Comment: Why did you cancel it according to your error?

Comment: How did you expect it to run something that _wasn't_ installed?

Comment: Generally, it helps us reduce the pollution of installing lots of packages on our machine. NPX allows you to run and use packages without needing to locally or globally install them.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding  what that's telling you. It's not the equivalent of `npm install {,--global}` because it doesn't _permanently_ install them, but they still have to be _temporarily_ installed to be usable at all.